# How to configure NTLM Authentication and use it in Java?

Tags: java, http, authentication, ntlm, ntlmv2

I have few questions related to NTLM.

Is NTLM configurations possible with Windows and access via any client supporting NTLM via http/https?

I have tried configuring in windows7 as per the link
http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/08/16/enabling-of-ntlm-on-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx
Is it enough to configure this for NTLM authentication ?

But could not succeed in Testing via client using SOAP UI.

PLease Please revert back with any kinda feedback :(

Thanks in Advance

Comment: 'Could not succeed' is not a problem description. Hard to see what an article about configuring Windows Server relates to Java.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for your reply. Yes i know it is not a problem description. It would be great if i get some idea on how to set up for NTLM correctly. By Java i meant in my case i am using Java to authenticate.